# EXCEL find the last relative maximum in a array (formula, not VBA)

Tags: excel-formula, max

I have a range containing values such as:

```
169.7978
168.633
168.5479
168.7819
167.7407
165.4146
165.1232
```

I don't need the maximum value of the range, i.e., the first cell in this example), but the last relative maximum, which in this case is the fourth cell. Is there a way to get this value **without** having to write a VBA macro? The formula must be general enough to work with a multiple number of maxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bit limited, but you may start somewhere as below.

Stated array in the OP is:

```
+----------+---+
|    y     | x |
+----------+---+
| 169.7978 | 1 |
| 168.633  | 2 |
| 168.5479 | 3 |
| 168.7819 | 4 |
| 167.7407 | 5 |
| 165.4146 | 6 |
| 165.1232 | 7 |
+----------+---+
```

[image: RelativeMixMaxDistro]

Given this, you can find direct adjacency relative min/max with the following helper columns

[image: RelativeMaxMinValues]
[image: RelativeMaxMinR1C1]

Assign a Global_Rank helper column and look for y distro identical trend on both adjacent `f(x)` with the following formulas ( assuming your data is sorted by the `x` index )( formulas from Row 2 and filled down ).

**RelativeMax:**
`=IF(AND(D2<=D1,D2<=D3),"RelativeMax","")`

**RelativeMin:**
`=IF(AND(D2>=D1,D2>=D3),"RelativeMin","")`

Modify as needed. Hope this helps.

#### Edit:

*Although...*

If you're going to assume the data is ordered properly, you could also just use `=IF(AND(B2>=B1,B2>=B3),"RelativeMin",IF(AND(B2<=B1,B2<=B3),"RelativeMax",""))` and skip all the malarkey. This should work with multiple maxima/minima. Please report back with results from your dataset!

Comment: Hi, for "ordered properly" you mean that the y column is increasing x order, right? Yes - of course it is. I'll test it on Monday and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @DeltaIV yup, that's correct. Need to keep the data indexed in order for the formulas to work. If you're going to be re-sorting or aren't sure that the data will be in index order, you'll want to use a `VLOOKUP` or similar to get the proper value on either side of the `>=` / `<=` operator. Good luck with your test! Please post back with success or failure.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post! Anyway, it worked flawlessly. Thanks again!